# Polyline endpoint query layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: point, line, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, query-layer

I have an Oracle 18c/SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline FC (15,000 features).

I want to create a query layer (or db view) that will display the startpoints and endpoints of the lines in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Is there a way to create a query layer that will dynamically display those points?

---

Related:

- ArcGIS Pro Community - [Dynamic endpoints layer](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/dynamic-endpoints-layer/td-p/1172662).
- [Improve performance of startpoint query (ST_GEOMETRY)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430866/improve-performance-of-startpoint-query-st-geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ST_GEOMETRY functions:

I've had a lot of problems trying to create queries using ST_GEOMETRY functions -- when the query returns an `ST_POINT subtype` shape: [ArcGIS Pro crashes when copying Oracle view to FGDB](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-crashes-when-copying-oracle-view-to/m-p/1172088).

And ST_GEOMETRY functions are generally too slow for this kind of thing. For example, this would take 20 seconds to run on 15,000 features:

```
select
    sde.st_x(sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometryn(shape,1))) shape
from
    active_transportation
```

---

So an alternative idea might be:

Use the linear referencing functionality in ArcGIS Pro (in conjunction with a non-spatial db view):

1. Create a db view that has a `point_evt_measure` column.

   - The measure value for startpoints is 0. The measure value for endpoints is: the total length of the line.
   - Note: This technique only works for cases where the polyline FC is M-enabled. And where the M-values have been entered as the *cumulative length of the line*. In other words, the last vertex's M-value is the same as the length of the line.

   > ```
   > create or replace view point_evt_measure_vw as (
   > select
   >     atn_id || '-' || 'START' as unique_id,
   >     atn_id,
   >     0 as point_evt_measure
   > from
   >     active_transportation
   > union all
   > select
   >     atn_id || '-' || 'END' as unique_id,
   >     atn_id,
   >     sde.st_length(shape) as point_evt_measure  --Unlike other ST_GEOMETRY functions, ST_LENGTH is actually quite fast, since it's stored as an "attribute" in the SHAPE object. 
   >     --https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm#:~:text=The%20perimeter%20length%20of%20the%20geometry
   > from
   >     active_transportation
   > )
   > ```

   [image]
2. In ArcGIS Pro, create a *Route Event Layer* that uses the `point_evt_measure` column from the view:

   [image]
   [image]

That seems to work.

---

Performance:

- The DB view is relatively fast: 1.2 seconds to select all rows in SQL Developer.
- But the Route Event Layer is a lot slower. It takes about 10 seconds to show the 30,000 start/endpoints. With that said, once the layer is initially drawn, it seems to be quite fast after that. Maybe ArcGIS Pro caches the data in RAM?

Ultimately, the performance is a tad slow. But the layer is still useful for exporting as a FC to other DBs, AGOL, etc.