# Get map to use function-based spatial index (ST_GEOMETRY)

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, performance, oracle-dbms, spatial-index, st-geometry

*SDE.ST_GEOMETRY — Oracle 18c — ArcMap/EGDB 10.7.1:*

I have a view that returns the startpoint of lines as an ST_GEOMETRY column:

```
create or replace view bc_atn_startpoint_vw as (
select
    objectid,
    sde.st_geomfromwkb(sde.st_asbinary(             --https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000011333            
        sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometryn(shape,1))
    ),sde.st_srid(shape)) as startpoint_shape
from
    infrastr.active_transportation --15,000 features
)
```

[image]

That view takes too long to load in the map in ArcMap (25 seconds).

I want to improve the performance of the query by creating a function-based spatial index on the resulting ST_GEOMETRY shape column.

---

**Basic non-spatial FBI test:**

As a basic test, I've created a non-spatial FBI that returns numeric XY columns, instead of an actual shape column. That test worked as expected. When I run the query in SQL Developer, the explain plan shows that the index was used, which is good. The query runs much faster, including when used as a XY layer in ArcMap.

The test was similar to what I did in this answer: [Improve performance of startpoint query (ST_GEOMETRY)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431019/62572).

By doing that test, I know that a FBI on a non-spatial column is working. That's a good start.

---

**Problem:**

I want to take this test a step further. Instead of creating a non-spatial FBI, I want to create a function-based **spatial** index, to improve the performance of the computed shape column.

But when I do that, I can't get SQL Developer or ArcMap to use the function-based spatial index when querying the computed features. So my view is still slow.

How can I get the map in ArcMap (or Pro) to use the ST_GEOMETRY function-based spatial index — for faster map performance?

---

**What I tried:**

```
create or replace function infrastr.st_startpoint(shape in sde.st_geometry) return sde.st_geometry 
deterministic is
begin
    return sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geomfromwkb_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_asbinary_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_startpoint_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1))),sde.st_geometry_operators.st_srid_f(shape)); 
end;

create index infrastr.atn_startpoint_st_idx on infrastr.active_transportation (st_startpoint(shape)) 
   indextype is sde.st_spatial_index  parameters ('ST_GRIDS= 320 ST_SRID=300125 ');

create or replace view bc_atn_startpoint_vw as (
select /*+ INDEX (active_transportation atn_startpoint_st_idx) */ --https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009658
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_unique_id,
    st_startpoint(shape) as shape
from
    infrastr.active_transportation 
where
    st_startpoint(shape) is not null --https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581129/5576771
)
```

That runs without errors. But the function-based spatial index still isn't being used by the map. It still takes 25 seconds to refresh the map (or run the query in SQL Developer).

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                       |   727 | 24718 |   181   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COUNT             |                       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION |   727 | 24718 |   181   (4)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("INFRASTR"."ST_STARTPOINT"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Related test: [Function-based index on object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72283908/function-based-index-on-object-type?noredirect=1#comment127704158_72283908)
2. In a test with ESRI Canada Support, we determined that using a `IS NOT NULL` WHERE clause actually makes things significantly slower. It made our query (not yet utilizing the FBI) twice as slow as it was without the WHERE clause. Not sure why.
3. With a different datatype (SDO_GEOMETRY), @DavidLapp(Oracle) advised, ["A spatial index is invoked only by the WHERE clause, not the SELECT list."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535550/5576771) I wonder if that applies to SDE.ST_GEOMETRY too. If so, that would explain why we're having this problem.

Comment: Why not do what the Esri Support article suggests as a workaround?  Why can't you use the st_geometry supertype or re-generate the geometries using the st_geometry constructor?  If you make the changes to the geometries than you won't have to deal with an FBI since the existing spatial indexes will likely be used.

Comment: @bixb0012 The article says *"Convert the geometry attribute field from the subtype (for example, st_point) to the supertype st_geometry."* If I understand correctly, the way to do that is to "fake it" by converting the resulting ST_POINT subtype geometry **to binary** (or WKT) and then convert that to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype. I do that in the original query and the in custom function: `sde.st_geomfromwkb(sde.st_asbinary(`. In other words, I think I'm already doing what you and the article suggest. [continued]

Comment: @bixb0012 ...The [ST_GEOMETRY constructors](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/constructor-functions.htm) are pretty limited. They only accept WKT or binary. We can't use them to directly convert a ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype. [continued]

Comment: @bixb0012 Regardless though, I don't think the subtype/supertype thing is the issue here. I think the issue is: computing a geometry (i.e. get startpoint) involves using slow ST_GEOMETRY functions. Sure, the original geometry we're querying is a static SHAPE field, which is good/fast. But the ST_GEOMETRY functions are slow. Once we change the geometry by extracting the startpoint, the resulting value is now computed, so it's not stored statically in a table or index. So displaying the startpoints in the map is way too slow. That's why I want to store the result of the calculation in a FBI.